# VLFeat Xcode c++

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, vlfeat

Im working on Xcode 7.2 Opencv 3.0 C++ and try to link VLFeat into the project. but some VLfeat function was working fine but when come to gmm and fisher it give error as in the picture.

I have compile the Xcode VLfeat program provided by the URL [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/xcode.html) 
Is anyone know how to solve this issues?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is library linkage issues where Xcode didn't found a path to connect with particular those files.

Solutions for this issues :

Additional steps beside of add 'search header path' and 'search library path'as below:-

Xcode : 
1) Goto 'Build Phases' at 'Link Binary With Libraries' add libvl.dylib

2) Also copy the libvl.dylib file placed 
at your project at location build/Debug/

Anyway this is works for me at the environment Xcode 7.2 c++